# What is the Django equivalence for Flask's UserMixin?

Tags: python, django

In Flask there is the `flask.ext.login.UserMixin` from the `flask-login` module.

I've tried to looked for the Django equivalence and the closest thing to the Flask's `UserMixin` is the `django.contrib.auth.models.User` from 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/auth/

Is that the Django's equivalence to Flask's `UserMixin`? What are the differences?

In [PyBossa, using Flask's UserMixin](https://github.com/PyBossa/pybossa/blob/master/pybossa/model/user.py), they have inherited from the UserMixin to add twitter/facebook `oauth`, can `django.contrib.auth.models.User` be inherited and sub-classed to do the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed. It's a model that stores information about a logged in User. Same thing.

You can either extend the model or replace it entirely.

> There are two ways to extend the default User model without substituting your own model. If the changes you need are purely behavioral, and don’t require any change to what is stored in the database, you can create a proxy model based on User. This allows for any of the features offered by proxy models including default ordering, custom managers, or custom model methods.

Extending Model:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model

Replacing User Model:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model

Comment: Thanks for the links!!